# Spoof Chrome & Mozilla from getting my actual screen resolution

Tags: google-chrome-extension, architecture, firefox-addon, mozilla

How do can i send different info from my original ones? I would like to change the monitor resolution only for the browsers, and if its possible and the fps too.
I don't want to do the developer tool of browsers, i need to change something at my computer so the browser took that info and show it.
I found this : `http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bfAYe/` but i don't know how to use it.
I want to use this for bookmakers, like : `bet365`.

Comment: Browsers can access low level OS functions so you can't fool them via JavaScript code. You can fool *sites*, and to achieve that you need to [Insert code into the page context](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) in a content script with `run_at` set to `document_start`.